# Java Infinite Loop Problem - With Unknown Variable

Tags: java, variables, while-loop, infinite-loop

I'm working through a course from Coursera. I am trying to find a solution for their infinite while loop question with an unknown variable.

**The Problem Is:**

> ```
> int i = 1;
> while (<<?>>) {
>     i = i*n;
> }
> ```
>
> **What should be written in place of <<?>> so that the loop ends when i is at least 34**? You may assume **n** is an **int variable** that has been declared and given a value prior to this code (the value of n does not affect the answer to this question).

I tried for the condition, `i % 34 = 0`, `i<=34`, etc. but I couldn't find the right answer. And they aren't giving the solution for this problem.

How can I solve this problem without knowing n's value?

Comment: Don't just guess. Reason about it. What does it mean for `i` to be *at least* (not "bigger than", that's slightly different) 34? And what is the negation of that?

Comment: The condition in the `while` statement determines whether the loop should continue to run.  So if the loop should end when `i` is "at least 34" then under what condition should the loop continue to run?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`i<=34` is almost right, but the requirement is to end the loop **when `i` is at least 34**. I.e., if `i` is 34, the loop should **not** continue, which means you should use the `<` operator, not the `<=` operator:

```
while (i < 34) {
    i = i*n;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply bro, it is solved. Can u explain the logic of this problem? Actually i couldn't understand it.

Comment: @B4CK3NDD3V I thought I did, let me give it another try. The statement "t the loop ends when i is at least 34` means that the loop should end if i is 34 or greater - if we reverse that condition (since a `while` loop has a condition that defines when it **does** run), we get i is less than 34, or in java `i < 34`.